# How do I upload files to a Google Drive folder for which I have a shared link with edit permission?

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a Google Drive account with a folder that has been shared with an edit permission link.  While logged into another Google Drive account, I would like to upload some files, using drag and drop to a Chrome Browser window opened with the shared link.  Can this be done using a browser?  Can this be done with an app using google-drive-sdk?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this can be done. If you paste the link into the browser it should take you to the folder. In the corner of the screen there should be an add to drive button. Click it and it will add the shared folder to your drive. If you drag and drop files into that folder then it will add the files for the folder for everyone to see.

Comment: Thanks Cyber Ghost, you are correct, it does work.  However, my real question involves how to do this using the sdk.  I want my users to sign into my iPhone app using credentials for a different Google Drive.  My app will then manage data in the shared folder in a controlled fashion using a hard-coded or retrieved (secret) link to the shared folder.  I don't want users to be able to change-corrupt-delete shared files with a browser.  My app can get a list of the folder's files using the FileID embedded in the link.  But my app uploading files always seems to fail.  Do I just have a bug?